# How appropriate is it to fit a regression line through median values?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, linear

I have a data set of tone separation (ranging from 1-3 octaves, plotted on the x-axis) vs. subject performance (y axis) through which I am fitting a regression line. The problem is that I have many more measurements for some tones than others; that is for one x-value, I have 20 y-values (with a wide range of 40-90%), while for another, I have just a couple y-values (say, sitting at 85% and 90%).

When I plot the regression line through all the points, I get a very low correlation ($R^2=0.1$) while plotting it through just the means or median of the data gives me an $R^2$ of 0.55.

I am wondering which is more correct. On one hand, taking the medians gives much greater weight to the handful of points that just create the correlation, but on the other, the wide spread of y-values on just a couple of points may be erasing the correlation that would appear if the other x-values had the same number of measurements.

What do you think?

Comment: When using ordinary least squares linear regression (OLS) one has to check for outliers that will hopelessly bias correlation results. Questions back to you, 1) are you using OLS linear regression (you probably are) 2) are you asking for a least error prediction of y given x (what OLS does)? or 3) Do you want to know what the relationship between x and y is (what you probably want to know)? If the latter, you need to do something else, like Theil regression. If 2) you may have to trim outliers.

Comment: Could you explain how "performance" is measured?  Since it seems to be on a 0-100% scale, one would expect it to start near zero for narrow separation, go up close to 100% for wide separation, and never go beyond the 0-100% range.  That calls for a completely different approach: least squares is not applicable (and will give misleading results).  You need either a generalized linear model or a nonlinear re-expression of the response. The choice depends on what "performance" really is.

Comment: Do you have repeated measures for subjects?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! @Carl  I'm using the matlab function fit(...'poly1'), which looking through the help file is most likely OLS. I'm interested in the relationship between x and y, yes, if there is any. Tried Theil-Sen, and got a very similar slope.

Comment: @whuber "Performance" is subject accuracy at telling whether a tone came from one side or the other: correct trials/total trials.

Comment: And yes, @ssdecontrol, there are repeated measures for four subjects, but a different number of repeats for any tone (x-value), and not all subjects performed on every tone.

Comment: So performance is a ratio of counts.  OLS won't work correctly here.  You need a [Binomial GLM](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+glm).